# Scout Algolia doesn't delete when objectId is not Primary key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

When I import my model to Algolia I change the ObjectId to the value of another field. But it seems when I call delete() on my object it doesn't remove it from Algolia. To be more clear here is an example:

User{
id,
email
name
}

Algolia User {objectId :email,name}

is there a way to solve this issue? Does scout have a function to overwrite the original delete function similiar to toSearchableArray?

EDIT: I have requested this feature on [Scout GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/scout/issues/267) for anyone interested

Comment: Why do you replace the ObjectID?

Comment: @JulienBourdeau I want to be able to filter by it on my frontend and because the value is unique I don't wanna set it as a facet. Algolia allows you to filter on ObjectId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Algolia SDK to manually delete it.

```
    $client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client(env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID'), env('ALGOLIA_SECRET'));
    $index = $client->initIndex('index_name');
    $index->deleteObject($model->email);
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `config('scout.algolia.id')` instead of env. But I believe its the only way to do it 

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to create a custom driver and extend the AlgoliaEngine.

I wrote some docs about it:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/laravel/extending-scout#extending-algolias-driver

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have problem in your model. Go along convention:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Here you have similar issue: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/model-import-problem/3300/2

Comment: It deletes it from database so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: But if you change the object id (primary key) to store it in Algolia, why not also change the primary key of the object in Laravel? `protected $primaryKey = '{object}_id'` then you send it to Algolia

Comment: @HCK I understand and your point is valid. However, at this point, I have to go through major refactoring to change that.